# C++ error LNK2001 issue

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to cpp but have been in c# for a while. I am trying to run a simple console application but I receive this LNK2001 error message.

I have the main.cpp, and have added another class, Zeus, with files, Zeus.h and Zeus.cpp.

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include "Zeus.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Zeus::tick = 25.0;
    using std::cout;
    cout << "nothing";
}
```

Here is the Zeus.h:

```
static class Zeus
{
public:
    static void testing(void);
public:
    static double tick;
};
```

And here is the Zeus.cpp:

```
void Zeus::testing(void)
{
 //Doesnt get this far
 //But eventually something like
 // cout << "test " << Zeus::tick;

}
```

And here is the error message:

Error 20 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static double Zeus::tick"

Thanks,

Comment: well, it seems like you nowhere defined "tick", at least not in the code you showed us

Comment: Can anyone comment on the mid-function `using std::cout` statement? Is this placement encouraged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `Zeus::tick`, typically you would to that in the in the `Zeus.cpp` file. You have only declared it.

```
double Zeus::tick = 0.0;
```

Also, there is no `static class` in C++.

As an aside, free functions can be put in namespaces, as opposed to being static functions of classes. This is the preferred way in C++, unless there are strong reasons for the function to be static.

```
namespace Dionysus {
  void testing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: there's no definition of `Zeus::tick`. Add this to Zeus.cpp:

```
double Zeus::tick;
```

Oh, and in Zeus.h remove the `static` from

```
static class Zeus
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `main()` function you have, what do you mean by a statement `Zeus::tick = 25.0;`?
`Zeus` is a class. So to access the individual elements of it you need to create its instance. Its just like a structure where you first create its instance to access its individual elements.

Try the following:

```c++
int main() {
    Zeus myobject;

    myobject.tick = 25.0;
    /* Rest of the definition */ 
}
```

Comment: That will work (if the original error is fixed), but it's not necessary. `tick` is a static data member, so doesn't need an object. The code as originally written is fine.

Comment: Oh!! I did not see it was static!!